# Calling ASP1.1 Web method in ASP.NET4.0 web service geting Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

Here is the Scenario I want to call the ASP1.1 web method from SQL JOB (Stored procedure)
but I was getting internal server error (500).
But it successfully call ASP.NET4.0 url (invoking webservice).

So Now I am calling 1.1 web method from ASP.NEt4.0 web service

ASP.NET4.0

```
[WebMethod]
public  void CALLEV()
{                          
  EVAutoService.POSEVAutomation wsEVAuto = new EVAutoService.POSEVAutomation();
  wsEVAuto.AutomateEVForTodaySchPatient();
}
```

ASP1.1 WEB Method Code

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Function AutomateEVForTodaySchPatient()
            CheckPhySchPatEV(getStaffId())
End Function
```

Getting error message

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. --> String was not recognized as a valid Boolean. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at POS.EVAutoService.POSEVAutomation.AutomateEVForTodaySchPatient()
```

**I have also used webrequest in ASP.NET4.0 webservice to invoke 1.1 web method**

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(GetHWServiceURL());
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
          string urlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
          //Do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

But it did not worked But getting Net.WebException

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
```

As I am suspecting its due to some security exception as both usel on same server but both are separate project on localhost.

Comment: I ahev already added both projects web config <protocols>
    <add name="HttpSoap" />
    <add name="HttpPost" />
    <add name="HttpGet" />
    <add name="HttpPostLocalhost" />   
   </protocols>

Comment: It should be a data error. That means you are providing some input data wrong in your request message that's why that server is not able to generate response. For knowing exact field error catch your exception at client side or refer logs of server.

Comment: @user3090039 that is right. I was suspecting that I have fixed it now its working fine.